# How to read value of max-delivery-attempts from Java in a MessageListener

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10, activemq-artemis

I have configured the redelivery settings in Wildfly 10 configuration some thing like below.

```
<address-setting name = "jms.queue.MyQueue" 
redelivery-delay="2000" max-redelivery-delay="10000" max-delivery-attempts="5" 
max-size-bytes="10485760" address-full-policy="FAIL"/>
```

I haven't configured the DLQ which I want to do myself. 
When a message fails , I would like to move it to certain queue with the error in it. Unfortunately if I configure the DLQ, I only get the original message but not the reason why it failed.

For that I would like to read the JMSXDeliveryCount and decide if this is the last attempt. If so then Move it to some other queue myself with additional information.

is it possible to read the original setting as done in standalone-full.xml from my Queue while consuming the message?

Comment: If your consumer fail to process the message what gives you confidence that it will be in a condition to then send the message to the DLQ? The consumer could fail to process the message due to a crash or network issues that prevent it from sending the message to a DLQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `max-delivery-attempts` setting is not defined in the JMS specification so in order to retrieve it from the server you'll need to use the Wildfly management API. There are a couple of ways to do this - [native](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/The+native+management+API) or [HTTP](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/The+HTTP+management+API). To be clear, this will make your application difficult to port to other potential JMS providers and/or Java application servers.

To avoid having to use the Wildfly management API you might consider setting a special property on the message from the producer to indicate how many times it should be delivered. Then you could just read this property in your consumer application and compare it to `JMXSDeliveryCount`. If you don't want to change the producer application you could probably accomplish the same thing using an Artemis outgoing interceptor to set the property on the message as it's being delivered to the consumer.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I could used this approach to solve my problem.